# Unable to load libmain.so in Android studio and Unity as library

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in my graduation project, I add Unity as a library to Android Studio it works fine with my mobile, but when I try on the other Android mobile I got some weird error (unable to load **libmain.so**), I search a lot but I didn't find the answer.

Note: there is no compile or build error, only when I click on the button(on android project) to go to Unity project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in my case I solved by editing the project's gradle file which should be located in `your_project/Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle`

For an unknown reason my gradle file had this lines that prevented to pack libmain.so inside the apk therefore giving the unable to load libmain.so error

```
// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingoptions {
      exclude ('/lib/arm64-v8a/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
```

If you find this in your gradle file, try to comment `//` or remove the block.

Comment: it helped me https://github.com/f111fei/react-native-unity-view/issues/142

Comment: your_project/Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle where is this file? I don't see it

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a) link, I think it will help

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":your_aar_file_name")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do this but nothing happen :(

Comment: Similar issue from us, maybe with different scope, but in particular with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877735/how-to-solve-libmain-so-not-found-while-using-unity-as-a-library-in-android-ap

Answer (score 0):

Please add following line into your string.xml

```js
<string name="game_view_content_description">Game view</string>
```

After that add below snippet into your app level's gradle file

```js
defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
```